# How can I change the value of a computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

Is there a way to change the initial data of a computed property? When I tried to change the data with an input tag, the vue gave me a warning like **Write operation failed: computed property "searchField" is readonly**. In case you wonder why I make this simple case with a computed rather than the data property, it is just for simplicity in the forum. There is a reason why I make it with the computed one. Here is the code.

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="searchField" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      searchField() {
        return "";
     }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Use the computer setter: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**computed** properties are interesting when you apply some logic around data.
In your example you should first declare a **data** property, and then you can apply logic with getter / setter :

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="searchField" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      _searchField: ''
    }),
    computed: {
      searchField: {
        get() {
          return this._searchField
        },
        set(value) {
          this._searchField = value
        }
     }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: this is super ambiguous because you have a data and a computed property with the same name, and the computed is useless here because it just return the data

Comment: @FlorentBouisset You are right, it is ambiguous, but he also explains why computed values should be used only when you apply logic or compute (calculate) a new value based on your data state, OP should use a data property instead of a computed property if he is not going to make any change to it besides getting the value as it is or setting the value of "searchField" without any further changes.